# LDA vs QDA on the AT&T dataset, poor QDA performance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, discriminant-analysis, pattern-recognition

I am obtaining two very different accuracies for the AT&T face database when fitting the model with lda & qda. Before using QDA I first search for the ideal regularisation parameter, AFAIK the only import parameter to fine-tune for QDA.

```
X_load,y_load = datasets.fetch_olivetti_faces(data_home="R:/DATASET/AT&T", return_X_y=True)
```

I split this into a balanced train and test sequence (8 images for training, 2 for testing per person)

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd')
lda.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_lda = lda.predict(X_test)
y_true_lda = y_test
f1_scores_lda.append(met.f1_score(y_true_lda, y_pred_lda, average='micro'))

qda = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf = GridSearchCV(qda, params, cv=4)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
reg_params_qda.append(clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
```

Im running this experiment for an increasing number of persons so Im keeping a python list with these parameters

```
qda2 = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(reg_param=clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
qda2.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_qda = qda2.predict(X_test)
y_true_qda = y_test
f1_scores_qda.append(met.f1_score(y_true_qda, y_pred_qda, average='micro'))
```

When i run this using the whole dataset (40 persons);

f1_scores_lda outputs 0.975

f1_scores_qda outputs 0.125

When i run this for 10 persons;

f1_scores_lda outputs 0.9

f1_scores_qda outputs 0.3

**Why is QDA performing so poorly?**

I'm getting "Variables are collinear" warning for QDA, what can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, QDA needs to be trained on less features! (Images are 64x64 pixels => 4096 features)

LDA can be used for dimensionality reduction in a first step, keeping let's say 6 discriminating features.

In this subspace, you can train a QDA classifier and on the AT&T dataset it slightly outperforms LDA. (see picture below, for 5 fold crossvalidation using the entire dataset)

My mistake was that in a rush I trained it like I trained LDA, forgetting QDA can't do dimensionality reduction.

[image: 5 fold crossvalidation scores on AT&T]

Some code to illustrate this;

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd')
crossval_scores_lda.append(cross_val_score(lda, X_load, y_load, cv=5))

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(solver='svd', n_components=6)
X_load_qda = lda.fit_transform(X_load, y_load)
qda = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis()
clf = GridSearchCV(qda, params, cv=4)
clf.fit(X_load_qda, y_load)
reg_params_qda_after_LDA.append(clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
qda2 = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(reg_param=clf.best_params_['reg_param'])
crossval_scores_qda.append(cross_val_score(qda2, X_load_qda, y_load, cv=5))
```